# Show that $\psi_v:\mathbb{K}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\times X $ given by $\psi_v(\xi)=(\xi,v)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $v\in X$. Then the following mapping is continuous $$\begin{align*}
\varphi _v:\mathbb{K}&\rightarrow X \\ 
\xi &\mapsto \xi v. 
\end{align*}$$

*Proof.* For any $\xi\in\mathbb{K}$, we have $\varphi_v(\xi)=M(\psi _v\left ( \xi  \right ))$, where $\psi_v:\mathbb{K}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\times X $ given by $\psi_v(\xi)=(\xi,v)$ is clearly continuous by definition of product topology and $M:\mathbb{K}\times X$ is the scalar multiplication in the topological vector space. $X$ which is continuous by definition of topological vector space. Hence, $\varphi_v$ is continuous as composition of continuous mappings.

My question is:

- Why $\psi_v$ is continuous  by definition of product topology? I have looked for the definition here [Product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition) but there is no information that I need.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B, C$ be topological spaces. A function $\phi : A \to B \times C$ is continuous iff the functions $p_B \circ \phi : A \to B$ and $p_B \circ \phi : A \to C$ are continuous, where $p_B : B \times C \to B$ and $p_C : B \times C \to C$ are the projection maps. This is known as the universal property of the product topology on $B \times C$.

We have $p_{\mathbb K} \circ \psi_v = id_{\mathbb K}$ which is continuous. Moreover $p_X \circ \psi_v$ is the constant map with value $v$ which is also continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\xi  \in \mathbb K$ and $U$ be an open neighborhood of $(\xi,v)$ in $ \mathbb K \times X$. By definition of the product topology there exist open neigbhorhoods $V$ of $\xi$ in $\mathbb K$ and $W$ of $v$ in $X$ such that $V \times W \subset U$. Then $\psi_v(V) = V \times \{v\} \subset V \times W \subset U$. This shows that $\psi_v$ is continuous in $\xi$.

Comment: Thank you so much!